# Most efficient way to union two tables including all data from first and missing data from second

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a two tables, one with user selected policies and another with all policies:

```
-- Policies selected by client
create table client_policies (
  id number,
  client_id number,
  policy_id varchar2(30),
  policy_description varchar2(100),
  policy_added_date timestamp,
  policy_modified_date timestamp
)
/

-- All available policies
create table policies (
  policy_id varchar2(30),
  policy_description varchar2(100)
)
/
```

example data:

```
insert into client_policies values (1, 123, 'HOUSE_INSURANCE', 'house insurance policy', sysdate - 10, sysdate - 3);
insert into client_policies values (2, 123, 'HEALTH_INSURANCE', 'health insurance policy', sysdate - 20, sysdate - 5);
insert into client_policies values (3, 123, 'CIVIL_LIABILITY_INSURANCE', 'civil liability insurance policy', sysdate - 2, sysdate - 1);

insert into policies values ('HOUSE_INSURANCE', 'house insurance policy');
insert into policies values ('HEALTH_INSURANCE', 'health insurance policy');
insert into policies values ('CIVIL_LIABILITY_INSURANCE', 'civil liability insurance policy');
insert into policies values ('CAR_INSURANCE', 'car insurance policy');
insert into policies values ('ETC_INSURANCE', 'etc... insurance policy');
```

There's two scenarios:

- user sees only his currently selected policies
- user sees his currently selected policies and all others which he haven't yet selected

I have a cursor which produces desired output, however It's lacking performance wise. My question is how can this improved or if there's another, better solution to this problem?

```
declare
  cursor c_get_client_policies(CP_CLIENT_ID            in number,
                               CP_GET_DEFAULT_POLICIES in varchar2) is
    with policies_data as
     (select 1 rank,
             id,
             policy_id,
             policy_description,
             policy_added_date,
             policy_modified_date
        from client_policies cp
       where client_Id = CP_CLIENT_ID
      union
      select 2                  rank,
             null               id,
             policy_id,
             policy_description,
             null               policy_added_date,
             null               policy_modified_date
        from policies p
       where CP_GET_DEFAULT_POLICIES = 'Y'),
    ranked as
     (select row_number() over(partition by policy_id order by rank) row_no,
             pd.*
        from policies_data pd)
    select id,
           policy_id,
           policy_description,
           policy_added_date,
           policy_modified_date
      from ranked
     where row_no = 1
     order by id;
begin
  for r in c_get_client_policies(123, 'Y') loop
    dbms_output.put_line('ID=' || r.id || ', POLICY_ID=' || r.POLICY_ID ||
                         ', POLICY_DESCRIPTION=' || r.policy_description ||
                         ', POLICY_ADDED_DATE=' || r.POLICY_ADDED_DATE ||
                         ', POLICY_MODIFIED_DATE=' ||
                         r.POLICY_MODIFIED_DATE);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

| ID | POLICY_ID | POLICY_DESCRIPTION | POLICY_ADDED_DATE | POLICY_MODIFIED_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | HOUSE_INSURANCE | house insurance policy | 2021.06.11 18:27:02,000000 | 2021.06.18 18:27:02,000000 |
| 2 | HEALTH_INSURANCE | health insurance policy | 2021.06.01 18:27:02,000000 | 2021.06.16 18:27:02,000000 |
| 3 | CIVIL_LIABILITY_INSURANCE | civil liability insurance policy | 2021.06.19 18:27:02,000000 |  |
|  | CAR_INSURANCE | car insurance policy |  |  |
|  | ETC_INSURANCE | etc... insurance policy |  |  |

Comment: isn't it just a left join??

Comment: This is a simple left join at the moment, but your previous question suggested there was more logic involved - possibly, for this version, which client policy to show if there are several?

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes I failed to formulate previous question correctly. It's seems that it really is a simple left join, can't think how I missed that... Client can only have unique policies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straight forward left join appears to do exactly what you're describing?

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=032e5e5f0a1856636f2ba144fd9eb390

```
SELECT
  client_policies.id,
  policies.policy_id,
  COALESCE(client_policies.policy_description, policies.policy_description)  AS policy_description,
  client_policies.policy_added_date,
  client_policies.policy_modified_date  
FROM
  policies
LEFT JOIN
  client_policies
    ON  client_policies.policy_id = policies.policy_id
    AND client_policies.client_Id = CP_CLIENT_ID
WHERE
     client_policies.policy_id IS NOT NULL
  OR CP_GET_DEFAULT_POLICIES = 'Y'
```

Comment: `OR CP_GET_DEFAULT_POLICIES = 'Y'` currently does nothing since `policies.policy_id` is never null, should probably be `WHERE client_policies.id IS NOT NULL OR CP_GET_DEFAULT_POLICIES  = 'Y';`

Answer (score 1):

To improve performance, you should replace your "union" by "union all" since you are using litterals 1 or 2 to separate the lines inside the policies_data view. UNION does an implicit distinct operation.